# execute a script for minimum 1 second

Tags: php

Here is my pseudo code

```
For loop repeat 30 times
Call and execute API script which takes less than 1 second
I want the system to sleep for some moment(less than 1 second)
Loop end
```

I want the above script should finish execution in minimum of 30 seconds (2-3 seconds longer is not a problem but must not less).
Can you write a sample code for me(only time related)

Comment: `sleep(30)`, maybe?

Comment: Have a look now. Its line by line meta code not actual php code. But all can easily understand what i am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little program that implements the essence of what I believe you are looking for:

```php
$minTime = 30;
$perSec = 10000;

$start = microtime(TRUE)*$perSec;
print("This must take $minTime seconds.\n");

// Replace this loop with what you actually need done
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) { print("Doing stuff #{$i}... "); sleep(1); }

// Check difference in timestamps to calculate remaining time
$remain=($minTime*$perSec-(microtime(TRUE)*$perSec-$start))/$perSec;

var_dump(['remain' => $remain]);

if ($remain > 0) {
    print("\n$remain seconds remaining... ");
    sleep($remain);
}

print("DONE\n");
```

This code has been updated to use `microtime()` instead of `time()`, which only permitted intervals of integer seconds. On systems that support `gettimeofday()` we can work with microseconds, instead.

Comment: say doing stuff takes 0.75 second. i need sleep time 0.25 second. not 1 second.